# Change radiobutton state from api data - React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Im getting data from an api where i have posted some answers from radio button. Im doing a functionality where users can save their progress and can continue later. Here is the radiobuttons code :

```
const [answers, setAnswers]= useState([]);
const [evQuestions, setEvQuestions] = useState([]);

const getEvaluationsQuestionsByOrganizations = async () => {
    await apiStandarts
      .get(`/evaluation-questions?organization=${stat.token}`)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.length) {
          for (const _res of res) {
            if (_res.questId) {
              _res["question"] = questions.find(
                (question) => question.questId === _res.questId
              );
               _res['question_option'] = _res.question?.question_options?.find(qOpt => qOpt.questOptionId === _res.questOptionId) ?? {}

            }
          }
        }
        // console.log(res)
        setEvQuestion(res.data);
        return res;
      });
  };

const isOptionSelected = (option) => {
    const answer = evQuestion;
    if(answer && route.params) {
      return answer.find(ans => option.id == ans.questOptionId )
    } else {
      const answer = answers[option.question]
      if(answer){
        return option.id == answer.id
      }
    }
    return false;
  };
  const OptionList = (groupOption) => {
    return groupOption.options.map((item, index) => {
      const fnSelectedOption = () => {
        const selectedOption = { [item.question]: { ...item } };
        setAnswers({ ...answers, ...selectedOption });
      };

      const status = isOptionSelected(item) ? true : false;

      return (
        <Radio
          initialValue={status}
          label={item.description}
          onChange={fnSelectedOption}
          color="rgba(0,0,0,.54)"
          radioInnerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#3671a6' }}
          labelStyle={styles.label}
          containerStyle={{ width: DEVICE_WIDTH * 0.8, paddingVertical: 5 }}
          key={item.id}
        />
      );
    });
  };
```

Here is the get request:

```
 const loadStepData = async () => {
      let value = null
      questions.map((question) => {
        const foundEvQuestion = evQuestion.find(evQuestion => evQuestion?.question?.questId === question.questId)
         value = foundEvQuestion?.questOptionId
         const values = value
      });
      return values;
    }
```

Here is the json of the data:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "created_at": "2022-02-16T09:56:08.052Z",
    "id": 913,
    "organization": 179,
    "organization_evaluation": null,
    "questId": 1,
    "questOptionId": 4,
    "question": null,
    "question_option": null,
    "question_option_points": 4,
    "updated_at": "2022-02-18T15:13:33.266Z",
  },
  Object {
    "created_at": "2022-02-16T10:28:39.349Z",
    "id": 930,
    "organization": 179,
    "organization_evaluation": null,
    "questId": 2,
    "questOptionId": 7,
    "question": null,
    "question_option": null,
    "question_option_points": 2,
    "updated_at": "2022-02-21T11:54:04.784Z",
  },
  Object {
    "created_at": "2022-02-16T11:19:12.924Z",
    "id": 947,
    "organization": 179,
    "organization_evaluation": null,
    "questId": 3,
    "questOptionId": 9,
    "question": null,
    "question_option": null,
    "question_option_points": 1,
    "updated_at": "2022-02-18T15:30:24.020Z",
  },
```

Updated the code.I pass a hash in the route.params that corresponds to user when he saved the data. The radio button now come checked but cant change their value anymore.
Now how can i change the radio button initial state based on this data? Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Where do you put the data of API responses? because you created a map over groupOption.options so when you get the data from endpoint you should to set them in the state groupOption as state variable

Comment: I put my data in a state variable but when i change the isOptionSelected function the radio button cant be clicked anymore

Comment: Can you add the complete codes related to this issue

Comment: Sure i did some progress i will update the code right now